# How do i remove the unused files from my website

Tags: asp.net, resource-cleanup

we have a legacy website where i see lots of dlls and files not used .and the size of the website folder is so big around 40GB .Is there any way to find out the unsued files(dlls,flat files) and remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using Resharper Extension from Microsoft. More information can be found from

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JetBrains.ReSharper

Thanks
Anurag